# Cutom wp_query for geolocation search, pagination not working

Tags: wp-query, customization, pagination, search

I have a custom search form that ends up on a page-template.php which then performs two WP_Query's. This is for a real estate where each property CPT has a long / lat value set via ACF. The code is partially based on https://pagecrafter.com/radial-search-results-page-wordpress-tutorial/. The issue I am having is with pagination. I've not yet tried adding a reqrite rule so wordpress understands pagination on this page-template

**The first query**

Gets property IDs that are within a search radius and does some meta query filtering based on the passed search parameters. It outputs an array pf property IDs that are sorted by distance from the searched postcode.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

$proximity = (int)get_query_var( 'radius' );
$zip2 = normalise( htmlspecialchars( get_query_var( 'q' ) ) );
$bedrooms = (int)get_query_var( 'beds' );
$property_type = get_query_var( 'property_type' );
$price_min =  get_query_var( 'min' );
$price_max =  get_query_var( 'max' );
$sale_sstc =  get_query_var( 'sstc' );
$sale_uo =  get_query_var( 'uo' );

if ( splitpostcode( $zip2 ) == FALSE ) {

    echo 'Not a postcode, do something else';

} else {

        $args = array();
        $args['post_type'] = 'properties';
        $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
        $args['posts_per_page'] = -1;
        $args['paged'] = $paged;

        //$meta_query = array();
        $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );

        if( isset($property_type) ) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'        =>    'type',
                'value'        =>    $property_type,
                'compare'    =>    '='
            );
        }

        if( isset($bedrooms) ) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'        =>    'bedrooms',
                'value'        =>    intval($bedrooms),
                'compare'    =>    '>='
            );
        }

        if( isset($price_min) ) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'        =>    'price',
                'value'        =>    intval($price_min),
                'compare'    =>    '>='
            );
        }

        if( isset($price_max) ) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'        =>    'price',
                'value'        =>    intval($price_max),
                'compare'    =>    '<='
            );
        }

        $property_status[] = 'Available';

        if( isset($sale_sstc) ) {
            $property_status[] = 'Sold Subject to Contract';
        }

        if( isset($sale_uo) ) {
            $property_status[] = 'Under Offer';
        }

        //print_r($property_status);

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'        =>    'status',
            'value'        =>    $property_status,
            'compare'    =>    'IN'
        );


        if(!empty($meta_query)) {
            $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
        }

        //print_r($args);


        $get_locations = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        $results = array();

        if ( $get_locations->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $get_locations->have_posts() ) {
        $get_locations->the_post();

                $next_lat = getlntsql($zip2);

                $zip1 = get_field( 'postcode' );
                $lat1 = (float)get_field('latitude' );
                $lon1 = (float)get_field('longitude' );
                $postid = get_the_ID();

                $lat2 = (float)$next_lat[0]->latitude;
                $lon2 = (float)$next_lat[0]->longitude;
                $theta = $lon1-$lon2;

                $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
                $dist = acos($dist);
                $dist = rad2deg($dist);

                $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;

                if ( $miles < $proximity ) {
                    //$data[$key] = $value;
                    //array_push($results, $postid);
                    $results[$postid] = $miles;

                }


        } } else { echo 'none!'; }

        wp_reset_postdata();
        asort( $results, SORT_NUMERIC );

        var_dump( $results );

}
```

**The second query**

Grabs the properties in the $results array for display

```
        <!-- Listings -->
        <div class="listings-container grid-layout-three">

        <?php

        wp_reset_query();

        $args2 = array(
            'post_type' => 'properties',
            'post__in' => array_keys($results),
            'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
            //'offset' => ($paged -1) * 9,
            //'paged' => $paged,
            'orderby' => 'post__in',
            'order'   => 'ASC',
        );

        $the_query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 ); 
        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query2->the_post(); ?>

            <!-- Listing Item -->
            <div class="listing-item">

                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" class="listing-img-container">

                    <div class="listing-badges">
                        <span><?php the_field( 'status' ); ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="listing-img-content">
                        <span class="listing-price">£ <?php echo number_format( get_field( 'price' ) ); ?><i><?php if ( get_field( 'bedrooms' ) !== '0' ) { $bedrooms = sprintf( ngettext("%d Bedroom", "%d Bedrooms", get_field( 'bedrooms' )), get_field( 'bedrooms' ) ); echo $bedrooms; } ?></i></span>

                    </div>

                    <?php 

                    $images = get_field('gallery');

                    if( $images ): ?>

                    <!-- Slider -->
                    <div class="listing-carousel">

                        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                            <div><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt=""></div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </a>

                <div class="listing-content">

                    <div class="listing-title">
                        <h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_field( 'type' ); ?> in <?php the_field( 'area' ); ?></a></h4>

                        <?php 

                            $title_location = esc_html( get_the_title() ); 
                            $title_location_formatted = str_replace(" ", "+", $title_location);

                        ?>

                        <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $title_location_formatted; ?>&hl=en&t=v&hnear=<?php echo $title_location_formatted; ?>" class="listing-address popup-gmaps">
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                            <?php echo $title_location; ?>
                        </a>

                    </div>

                    <?php

                    $date = get_field('onmarket', false, false);

                    // make date object
                    $date = new DateTime($date);

                    ?>

                    <?php

                    $lat1 = (float)get_field('latitude' );
                    $lon1 = (float)get_field('longitude' );
                    //$distance = getDistance($lat1, $lon1, $zip2); 

                    //$next_lat = getlntsql($zip2);


                    $lat2 = (float)$next_lat[0]->latitude;
                    $lon2 = (float)$next_lat[0]->longitude;

                    $theta = $lon1-$lon2;

                    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
                    $dist = acos($dist);
                    $dist = rad2deg($dist);

                    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;

                    $zip1 = get_field('postcode');

                    if (isset($miles)) {
                    $miles = number_format( $miles, 2 ); ?>
                    <p style="font-weight:bold; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0;"><?php echo $miles; ?> Miles from <?php echo $zip2; ?></p>

                    <?php } ?>


                    <div class="listing-footer">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> Published: <?php echo get_the_date( 'j M Y' ); ?></a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Listing Item / End -->

        <?php 
        }

        $big = 999999999;
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
            'total' => $the_query2->max_num_pages,
        ) ); 


        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

        </div>
        <!-- Listings Container / End -->
```

**Edit 1**

After some faffing, I realised the paged parameter wasn't working as expected. If you are on a page-template.php (page), rather than a archive-post.php (post), then to get the $paged parameter:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
else { $paged = 1; }
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Static_Front_Page

Answer (score 0):

Key to this was the $paged parameter and putting it in the correct query

New code for getting the paged parameter for a 'page'

```
    if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
    elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
    else { $paged = 1; }
```

The first query (I don't think I need orderby as I am custom ordering the results by lng/lat)

```
    $args = array();
    $args['post_type'] = 'properties';
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
    $args['posts_per_page'] = -1;
    $args['orderby'] = 'ID';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
```

The second query

```
    $args2 = array(
        'post_type' => 'properties',
        'post__in' => array_keys($results),
        'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
        'offset' => ($paged -1) * 9,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby' => 'post__in',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
    );
```

Hope this helps someone in the future